# How to deploy a angular app that isn't scaffolded with yeoman

Tags: angularjs, heroku

I have a angular app, just a angular app so no nodejs or other backend is involved. I have a separate backend setup with an API. My angular app communicates to the backend with the API.

Now when I want to put my angular app online, how do I do this? If I just put the html files online I get all kinds of errors (I already have a separate question for this matter, which is unresolved). Deploying to heroku doesn't work because it isn't a nodejs app.

So how is this accomplished?

Comment: you need either node or iis or whatever framework which should server the static contents when requested, thats all to hosting website like yours...

Comment: how can I implement node or iis when my app is already in development?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an apache server or nginx to serve static content on a remote server. Personnaly I use Nginx, it doesn't require a lot of configuration (almost no configuration) to works.

Comment: this doesn't work, when I put my angularapp on mydomain.com/angularapp i get all kinds of 404 not found errors from all of my files

Comment: try to use the same configuration on your desktop and see if it works or not, i think it should be a configuration problem of your server.